# can't solve the (java.lang.NullPointerException) problem

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

***i got that when executing the code below:
(the problem seems to be with the insert method but can't really figure it out)
(i would appreciate if you point out the solution)*****

```
        public void writeBit(char bit) throws IOException{
            b.insert(0, bit);
            if(b.length()==8){
                a.write(Integer.parseInt(b.toString()));
                b.setLength(0);
            }
        }
```

[The whole code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlSEH.png)

Comment: You never initialize `b`?

Answer (score -1):

Private StringBuilder b is never instantiated.